# Flex Custom Component problem

Tags: apache-flex, flex3

I've made a custom component based on MenuBar. This is the code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mx:MenuBar xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml"
    width="100%" 
    labelField="@label">
    <mx:XMLList>
        <menuitem label="Website" />
    </mx:XMLList>
</mx:MenuBar>
```

The problem is that the "Website" isn't displayed.

**EDIT**

I found the correct syntax and it's working now

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mx:MenuBar xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml"
    width="100%" 
    labelField="@label" dataProvider="{menuXmlListCollection}">
    <mx:XMLListCollection id="menuXmlListCollection">
        <mx:XMLList>
            <menuitem label="Website" />
        </mx:XMLList>
    </mx:XMLListCollection>
</mx:MenuBar>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this same thing with a ArrayCollection:

`private var menuXmlListCollection: ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection([
    { label: "Website"},
    { label: "Webmail"},
    { label: "Blog"}];`